# How to read DeviceInformation properties within the Windows.Devices namespace

Tags: c#, uwp, smartcard

I have a smart card reader and I want to know when the reader is added or removed.

I have set up a DeviceWatcher with a few events.

```
devWatcher = Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher();

devWatcher.EnumerationCompleted += DeviceWatcher_EnumerationCompleted;
devWatcher.Added += DeviceWatcher_AddedAsync;
devWatcher.Removed += DeviceWatcher_Removed;
devWatcher.Updated += DeviceWatcher_UpdatedAsync;

devWatcher.Start();
```

If I under stand [the Microsoft developer ref the DeviceWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher?view=winrt-19041) will enumerate all device at first so I wait for the EnumerationComplete event.  If the device is already added at this point then any changes are shown in the Updated event.  From what I can see if I remove the device then the Removed event and Update event fires. If I add it back then just an update event occurs.

I therefore want to understand from the [DeviceWatcher.UpdatedEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher.updated?view=winrt-19041) what the status of the device is. I assume I need to get this from the properties of the DeviceInformationUpdate which is supplied in the Update event.

I understand I need to get this information from the [device information properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/device-information-properties) however I am lost on which device kind is available and which property from that kind to use and if I understand it correctly the properties are not always available for each device.

Comment: `CreateWatcher` contains `DeviceClass` parameter  overload method, you could use it to specific which kind of device you want  to watch.

Comment: I don’t know all the devices, unless you know a way to filter it to Card Reader devices.

Comment: Have you check this code sample [smartcard](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SmartCard)

Comment: During the test my smartcard read kind is [`DeviceInterface`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ddg27.png)

Comment: How can either of those suggestions help if the smart card reader is NOT connected? Further I think that there will be a few other devices that are also a DeviceInterface.

Comment: Yep, you could use DeviceInterface as selector to filter devices then use displyname to filter again.